# Python script read from a file input file and writes to a file

Tags: python

### Hello, i need this Javacode in python

I have programmed in Java, but i need this code in python

### The script is typed from a file read and write again in a file.

Input File

- cc_oo_g_csss.sh
- cc_oo_guv_zppp.sh
- cc_aba_ddd.sh
- cc_aba_ccxyp.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part1.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part2.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part3.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part4.sh
- c_abus_pl_fa_part5.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part6.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part7.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_part8.sh
- cc_abus_pl_fa_merge.sh
- cc_abac_nsv_ssd.sh
- cc_abac_kriv.sh
- cc_rufrep_nia_inst_leg.sh
- cc_rufrep_nia_inst_comb.sh
- cc_rufrep_nia_inst_flow.sh
- cc_rufrep_nia_inst.sh
- cc_vision_kriv.sh
- cc_vision_interface_part1.sh
- cc_vision_interface_part2.sh
- cc_vision_interface_part3.sh
- cc_vision_interface_part4.sh
- cc_vision_interface_merge.sh
- cc_vision_deriv.sh
- cc_ria_flows_rep_plain.sh
- cc_iaed_fls_rep_merge.sh

### I need as a file

cc_oo_g_csss.sh

cc_oo_guv_zppp.sh

cc_aba_ddd.sh

cc_aba_ccxyp.sh

D:\Temp\c_run_multiple_shell_skripts.sh

-S "cc_abus_pl_fauz_part1.sh, cc_abus_pl_fa_part2.sh, cc_abus_pl_fa_part3.sh, cc_abus_pl_fa_part4.sh, 
cc_abus_pl_fa_part5.sh, cc_abus_pl_fa_part6.sh, cc_abus_pl_fa_part7.sh, cc_abus_pl_fa_part8.sh "

-F cc_abus_pl_fa_merge.sh

cc_abac_nsv_ssd.sh

cc_abac_kriv.sh

cc_rufrep_nia_inst_leg.sh

cc_rufrep_nia_inst_comb.sh

cc_rufrep_nia_inst_flow.sh

cc_rufrep_nia_inst.sh

cc_vision_kriv.sh

D:\Temp\c_run_multiple_shell_skripts.sh

-S "cc_vision_interface_part1.sh, cc_vision_interface_part2.sh, cc_vision_interface_part3.sh, 
cc_vision_interface_part4.sh"

-F cc_vision_interface_merge.sh

cc_vision_deriv.sh

cc_ria_flows_rep_plain.sh

cc_iaed_fls_rep_merge.sh

public class shellsort {

```
public static Vector<String> sortforshell(String path) throws IOException{


    String[] input = readFile(path,Charset.defaultCharset()).split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    Vector<String> output = new Vector<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while(i<input.length){
        if(input[i].contains("part")){
            output.add("D:/hhh/cc_multiple_script.sh");
            String partLine = "-S ";
            partLine = partLine.concat(input[i]);
            String validate =input[i].substring(0,input[i].indexOf("part"));
            i++;
            while(input[i].contains("part")&&input[i].contains(validate)){
                partLine = partLine.concat(", "+input[i]);
                i++;
            }
            output.add(partLine);
            if(input[i].contains("merge")&&input[i].contains(validate)){
                output.add("-F "+input[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }else{
            output.add(input[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }


    return output;


}



static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)  throws IOException {

          byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
          return new String(encoded, encoding);

        }



public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    Vector<String> output = sortforshell("/input.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<output.size();i++){
        System.out.println(output.get(i));



    }



}
```

}

---

sjadjhdahs >
asdasda

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackoverflow is not a free code conversion service or a place to hire contract programmers.

Comment: Don't convert line-by-line, that's often a mistake.  Go back to the written specification and start coding from scratch.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. That's what I need ))

Answer (score 0):

Read file:

```
f = open('/tmp/file')
out = f.read()
f.close()
```

Write file:

```
f = open('/tmp/file','w')
f.write('some text')
f.close()
```

Simple enogh, huh?